# OWL: modeling a router

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, modeling, owl, ontology

I'm starting with OWL and I want to model a network router using it. For the modeling I'm doing, I need to represent:

- IP routes;
- IP routing tables.

So, for now, a router is a device that has a routing table. My idea is the following:

- To define a class "IP";
- To define a object property "nextHop" (having IP as range and domain);
- To define a class "Route", that is an IP (or prefix) that has another IP as nextHop;
- To define a clase "RoutingTable", that is a collection of "Route" individuals.

I started modeling a Class called "IPv4" (I'm going to do the "v6" after):

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about = "IPv4">
  <rdf:Description>
  <xsd:pattern>I'll put a regex for IPv4 here...</xsd:pattern>
</owl:Class>
```

Then, the next hop property:

```xml
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID = "nextHop">
    <rdfs:domain rdf: resource ="IPv4"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf: resource ="IPv4"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

Now, the Route and the RoutingTable:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="#Route">
    <rdfs:label>Route</rdfs:label>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
    <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
               <owl:Class rdf:about = "IPv4">
               <owl:Restriction>
          <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#nextHop"/>
          <owl:someValuesFrom>
                        <owl:Class rdf:about="#IPv4"/>
                  </owl:someValuesFrom>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>


<owl:Class rdf:about="#RoutingTable">
    <rdfs:label>RoutingTable</rdfs:label>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <owl:Class rdf:about="#Route"/>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

So, I ask: are these correct? Any tips? Where can I get some information about how to properly model using OWL? I've found some tutorials, but none of them has similar examples to what I'm trying to do...

Comment: This is probably too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  Based on your specification, we can take a guess as to whether the implementation is correct (but that's not quite a technical programming question), and questions like "any tips?", etc., are usually too broad and/or opinion based. Have you run into any particular problem with your implementation?

Comment: Question like "Where can I get some information about how to properly model using OWL? I've found some tutorials, but none of them has similar examples to what I'm trying to do...", while they can sometimes be useful, are off-topic on Stack Overflow: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Also, it's pretty clear that your XML isn't syntactically legal.  E.g., you've got an opening tag for an rdf:Description element and no closing tag.   Similarly for owl:Restriction, etc.  I'd recommend that you use an ontology editor like Protege to help ensure you end up with a legal ontology.